# UIView background color set is not what appears

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a UIView with a set background color. Lets say RGB value 185, 45, 42. For some reason, when I take a screenshot of this view, it is not that color. It is a little bit darker. Is there a reason why UIView would do this?

The UIView background color is set in interface builder like this:

[image: Color]

When I run it on the simulator and take a screenshot and use the eye drop tool to determine the color, the numbers that show up are a little bit darker than what I entered. Same with a button.

I have other screens with the same red color and the screenshot I take of those, the red actually comes out correctly. I've been trying to determine what the difference is between those screens, but so far have not seen any. So I was just wondering if anyone would have any knowledge of anything that "could" case such a color change.

Comment: Could we get some code please?

Comment: How are you viewing the screenshot, on a computer or on your phone? Is that RGB color from an image or file with different color space settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common mistake when setting a color numerically in Interface Builder is to neglect the color space:

[image]

Different color spaces will give different colors (visually) for the same RGB values.

Comment: You sir, are spot on! =) Tried this and it worked. Learned something new in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

When you set RGB color, you should notice that all the three color values range from 0 to 1, so give them a value greater than 1 would never work. Try this:

```
RGB(185 / 255.0, 45 / 255.0, 42 / 255.0)
```

Comment: How do you know this is the issue? This answer is premature until the OP provides more detail.

Comment: Actually I didn't, but since he give three number greater than 1 and  I've made this mistake before, so I just point out a possible reason.

Comment: He gave three numbers greater than 1 because that is what he sees in Interface Builder in the Colors window. That is where he is setting the colors. He said "a UIView with a set background color". It's not very well written but this likely means he's presetting the color in IB.